# Space between the cards

Tags: html, css, angular

guys I know there will be a question regarding this but I'm unable to find it. I need a gap between the cards in the grid view. Also Read more towards the right bottom will be helpful.
Thanks for the help

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile >
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutGap="20px">
        <div class="card mat-elevation-z3" >
        <h4 class="blogTitle">What is Test Anxiety and its symptoms</h4>
        <p>
          Whether you are an elementary school, junior high school, high school, college student,
          a professional career person taking continuous education, someone who is entering into a
          new career or preparing for a competitive exam, you may feel some amount of nervousness
          or feeling of anxiety when you
        </p>
        <a href="" style="color:blue">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile >
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutGap="20px">
        <div class="card mat-elevation-z3" >
          <h4 class="blogTitle">What is Test Anxiety and its symptoms</h4>
          <p>
            Whether you are an elementary school, junior high school, high school, college student,
            a professional career person taking continuous education, someone who is entering into a
            new career or preparing for a competitive exam, you may feel some amount of nervousness
            or feeling of anxiety when you
          </p>
          <a href="" style="color:blue">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH9o8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set a gutterSize on mat-grid-list

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1" gutterSize="8">
...
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Can you provide a Stackblitz?